# How can I keep pictures in memory with Picasso?

Tags: android, database, picasso

I'm viewing some pictures using *recyclview* with *Picasso*. 
These images are a bit too much to recompile in *recyclerview* and when I go up again, it reloads the pictures, and if the pictures are too big, or the network access is bad, it does not look nice.

I wonder how can I cache the pictures I called with *loadUrl* with *Picasso*. Is this possible with *Picasso*?

As an example I can give *Instagram*. Every time I go back to another activity, it loads the picture again and affects the performance of the application. If you teach me how to keep the pictures in memory, or if you show me a source, I'm happy. Thanks in advance.

My Code:

```
adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<WallPaperItem, ListWallPaperViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ListWallPaperViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull final WallPaperItem model) {

            Picasso.with(getBaseContext())
                    .load(model.getImageLink())
                    .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
                    .into(holder.wallpaper, new Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {



                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError() {

                            Picasso.with(getBaseContext())
                                    .load(model.getImageLink())
                                    .error(R.drawable.ic_wallpaper_black_24dp)
                                    .into(holder.wallpaper, new Callback() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSuccess() {



                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onError() {

                                            Log.e("ERROR","None");

                                        }
                                    });

                        }
                    });

                holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view, int position) {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(ListWallPaper.this,ViewWallPaper.class);
                        Common.selected_background = model;
                        Common.select_background_key = adapter.getRef(position).getKey();
                        startActivity(intent);


                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

why you use

```
 .into(holder.wallpaper, new Callback() {}
```

and check new callback

try this

```
Picasso.get().load(model.getImageLink())
.networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
.placeholder(R.drawable.user_placeholder)
.error(R.drawable.ic_wallpaper_black_24dp)
.into(holder.wallpaper);
```

maybe it help

Comment: Thank you for the answer. compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3: okhttp: 2.7.5'
     I solved that problem using the compile 'com.jakewharton.picasso: picasso2-okhttp3-downloader: 1.1.0' libraries, but now I'm facing another problem. Photos are uploading too late. Average 5-10 seconds. There are 30 photos in the list and it takes time to upload them all. I'm trying to solve this problem.